# Match the regex of 'word one occurs M times, then word two occurs N times' from a word sequence with comma as the splitter

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

There's a word sequence

`'dog,cat,dog,cat,dog,cat,bird,cat,bird'`

I'd like to match the regex that 'dog' occurs 3 times and then 'bird' occurs 2 times. So I write the regex as follow:

`^(((?!dog).)*dog){3}((?!(dog|bird)).)*(((?!bird).)*bird){2}((?!(bird)).)*$`

But the problem is that when I specified the frequency of 'dog' as 2 or 1, the regex still matches, this is not what I want.

So how can I do to match the ordered occurrences with times correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using negated lookaheads, you can use this regex:

```
^(?:(?:(?!dog).)*dog,){3}(?!.*dog)(?:(?:(?!bird).)*bird){2}(?!.*bird)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bCvDRE/1)

Note use `(?!.*dog)` and `(?!.*bird)` at the end of your keyword matches to prevent matching strings with more occurrences of these words.